# Python sorted() function that returns a dictionary - code optimizing

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I wrote a Python function that returns a dictionary and sorted, using sorted() function, but I would like to optimize my code, to skip the for loop, below is my current solution:

```
def new_sorting(pDict, pReverse):
    retDict = {}

    if len(pDict) > 0:
        keys_list = sorted(pDict.keys(), reverse = pReverse)

        for k in keys_list:
          retDict[k] = pDict[k]

    return retDict
```

Comment: This question would do better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Standard dictionaries are not ordered in Python. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key answer your question?

Comment: @Tomalak Standard dicts are insertion ordered [as of Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/11498682)

Comment: @Ahndwoo Ah, thanks. Good to know!

Comment: @Mohi2019, as stated above, please see the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9001529/236007 that doesn't involve an explicit for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly sort the key/value pairs and shove them back into a `dict` without named temporaries with just:

```
def new_sorting(pDict, pReverse):
    return dict(sorted(pDict.items(), reverse=pReverse))
```

`.items()` returns a view of two-`tuple`s of key/value pairs, `sorted` sorts them lexicograpically (since `dict` keys are unique, it should never need to compare the second item in the `tuple`), then the `dict` constructor takes the resulting `list` of sorted two-`tuple`s to make a new `dict` all at once.

Note that this requires CPython/PyPy 3.6, or any Python interpreter 3.7+; prior to those releases, the only way to preserve the ordering is to replace the use of `dict` with `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 1):

starting from python 3.6 this should work fine:

```
def new_sorting(pDict, pReverse):
    return {a: b for a, b in sorted(pDict.items(), reverse=pReverse)}
```

Comment: Thanks team, it worked well. I always learned new Python tricks from here...appreciated